# Mögen vs. möchten

Tags: grammar

Welcher Satz klingt hier besser und wieso?

> Ich mag es, Deutsch zu lernen und nach Deutschland zu fliegen.

Und

> Ich möchte Deutsch lernen und nach Deutschland fliegen.

Einige Deutsche sagen, dass Nr.1 besser klingt als Nr. 2 und wann verwendet man Nr. 1 und Nr. 2? Gibt es einen großen Unterschied?

Comment: I edited your title based on the body of the question. "Mögen" and "möchten" are two different verbs (or should be seen as such) and I don't see a problem making a distinction. Both sound equally good in their respective contexts. Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Emanuel: eigentlich sind das 2 Fragen in einer, nämlich wann man den Konjunktiv II von "mögen" (= möchte, *"möchten"* ist **kein** eigenes Verb) bildet, und wann eine Infinitivkonstruktion. Oder?

Comment: Man sollte auch dazu sagen, dass statt "Ich mag + Infinitivsatz" eher "Satz + gerne" verwendet wird; Ich lerne gerne Deutsch. Ich fliege gerne nach Deutschland. Mit Objekten, also ohne Verb, ist es natürlich: Ich mag Deutsch. Ich mag die Deutschen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nr. 1 bedeutet, dass es dir gefällt, Deutsch zu lernen. Du lernst also bereits Deutsch.

Mit Nr. 2 drückst du aus, dass du planst, Deutsch zu lernen.

Da die beiden Sätze sich in ihrer Aussage grundsätzlich unterscheiden, würde ich nicht beurteilen, welcher besser klingt.

Comment: Völlig richtig, aber ich möchte noch darauf hinweisen, dass der erste Satz nicht sehr natürlich klingt. Falls die Aussage des ersten Satzes gemeint ist, wäre folgende Formulierung besser: "Ich lerne gerne Deutsch und fliege gerne nach Deutschland".

Comment: @Stefan Dorner's Antwort ist die einzig relevante und zutreffende Antwort auf die Ausgangsfrage.
Alle anderen Antworten, die bisher gegeben wurden, können Antwortsuchende nur verwirren.
Auch die Ausgangsfrage ist in ihrem Ansatz schon falsch formuliert: es handelt sich eben nicht um eine Frage des sprachlichen Wohlklanges.
In der gestellten Frage wird der grundlegende Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen beiden Formen (mag vs. möchte) des Verbes "mögen" von vorn herein ignoriert. So führt die Frage die Leser und Antwortsuchenden von vorn herein in die Irre.

Answer (score 2):

mag = like, 
möchte = would like

mögen is a modal verb, so you use it directly with a verb and no "zu":

- Ich mag Deutsch lernen und nach Deutschland reisen. = 
  *I like learning German and traveling to Germany.*
- Ich möchte Deutsch lernen und nach Deutschland fliegen. = *I would like to learn German and fly to Germany.*

Answer (score 0):

In der Form "Ich möchte, dass ... " **wird verlangt, dass** etwas getan wird/passiert (**Befehl**)
*Aber:* "Ich mag, dass ... " drückt aus, dass es **gut wäre, wenn** etwas getan wird /passiert (**Bitte**)

Ansonsten stimmt die Aussage von @Stephan Dorner: *mögen* und *möchten* sind unterschiedliche Verben.

Comment: Vote down? Genau diese Gegenüberstellung von *möchten* und *mögen* hat den Author verwirrt!